# How I can check if a string is likely to be generated by a bot?

Tags: javascript, c#, string, random, bots

I have spam issue. Some bot (I believe) is getting around Google recaptcha and inserting strings like the following into forms on my site:

dtbNPRpfcz

VvAJEXqueSKscY

Does anyone know of any JS or C# code I can use that would give a high probability of indicating that the above string is randomly generated?

If I could check the fields being filled and know that several of them were likely to be bot generated then I could block the submission.

The above strings seem to have more than a normal number of ucase chars for example.

**Update:**  Currently looking at using a password strength checker against some of the strings. If the string is above weak then it's likely to be spam.  My web host said "try another recaptcha".

**Update:**

Well. I've learned a lot over this and gained some useful code so thank you very much for your input and answers.  However, after ignoring the problem for the weekend I looked at it again. I noticed that the spam bot was getting around ALL the form validation.  Then the penny dropped. The bot was going directly to route and posting to it.  I had not set up CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery). This meant an agent could post to the url from outside the site's domain.  Doh!

I had added this to the forms:

```
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

But some of my routes were missing the code to check it:

```
  try
            {
                this.ValidateCsrfToken();
            }
            catch (CsrfValidationException)
            {
                return Response.AsText("Csrf Token not 
valid.").WithStatusCode(403);
            }
```

So. Apologies for wasting your time. That fixed it immediately.

Comment: that's quite a broad subject for this site format. Also, it's nearly begging for external tools, which is off-topic (see [help/dont-ask])

Comment: if we stick to your examples, a simple comparison with a dictionary (plus or minus some fuzzy change) should do the trick. But I suspect you want much more complicated. Also, it will also depend on your performance requirements.

Comment: Also, to relate directly to your question, have you tried to count the capital letters in your string ?

Comment: What the page is supposed to send? A reasonable text in some human language? Are you sure the bot, or what ever it is, is using the page containing the Re-Captcha, or is the request send directly from a server?

Comment: Blimey. You guys are quick.  Yes. I am going to check with my ISP and see if they can't do something or have some tool.  I tried the ucase idea but it won't work because it's stuff like name, comment, country. Country might contain USA and name might be "John B Doe" etc.

Comment: The examples of the injected strings don't have spaces, maybe detect spaces for the first aid?

Comment: I don't think spaces will work either since they can be strings without spaces.

Comment: Put all the passed strings together, and require at least one space (if there's some data which must contain at leas a single space).

Comment: That won't work because country might be:  "USA".

Comment: "_all strings together_" ... The name is supposed to contain at least one spcace, isn't it?

Comment: It has to be smarter. For example you never get two vv's together in a string in English. You don't get "dt" and you don't get "pf" or "cz" very often.  Just thought there might be a function someone has written that runs a number of checks and returns true if there's a high chance the string is spam.

Comment: I know that if you send a an e-mail with a link to a site, and you have a form (with or without recaptcha), Microsoft's Outlook will probably try to submit a form using the link, with a random string as well. You still need to check if the recaptcha challenge was successful or not, because the bots (usually) don't pass the challenges I believe. I am not an expert on this area, but I remember that we had a scenario where our server logged errors because of some random string in an API, and it was Microsoft that did it automatically for users using Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random string detection is complicated and is related to machine learning. I don't recommend to implement it on your own, perhaps spell-checking JS/C# libraries do help.

Apart from that, regarding to bot prevention, I try to make a few suggestions:

- **Make sure you have implemented Google recaptcha correctly.** Use reCAPTCHA v3 if possible, and make sure you have verified g-recaptcha-response on backend side. Google recaptcha does not 100% reliable and can be bypassed by some Anti Captcha solutions, but correct implementation is the basic.
- **Filter out suspicious IP address.** Block the IP address from which randomly generated strings are sent out.

Comment: I put this as the answer since it made me check things over.

Answer (score 1):

Random 16-40 random character name script with .js extension and you can get to see information with below format in it like userAgentKey, timezoneKey, browserKey. You can check script in Sources tab or in Network tab with XHR and in JS information.
You can create regular expression to get required script information which will match file information. [A-Za-z0-9]{14,40}.js
For Example: ytpbsalvddssjopc.js

```
interrogate: function(e) {
                var t = {};
                t = this.userAgentKey(t),
                t = this.languageKey(t),
                t = this.screenKey(t),
                t = this.timezoneKey(t),
                t = this.indexedDbKey(t),
                t = this.addBehaviorKey(t),
                t = this.openDatabaseKey(t),
                t = this.cpuClassKey(t),
                t = this.platformKey(t),
                t = this.doNotTrackKey(t),
                t = this.pluginsKey(t),
                t = this.canvasKey(t),
                t = this.webglKey(t),
                t = this.touchSupportKey(t),
                t = this.videoKey(t),
                t = this.audioKey(t),
                t = this.vendorKey(t),
                t = this.productKey(t),
                t = this.productSubKey(t),
                t = this.browserKey(t),
                t = this.windowKey(t),
                t = this.locationKey(t),
                t.fonts = "",
                t.devices = null,
                this.keys = t,
                this.parallel([this.fontsKey, this.devicesKey], e)
```